# Array definition - Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c

I am creating an array on stack as

```
static const int size = 10;

void foo() {
..
int array[size];
..
}
```

However, I get the compile error: "expression must have a constant value", even though size is a constant. I can use the macro

```
#define SIZE (10)
```

But I am wondering why `size` marked `const` causes compilation error.

Comment: It's not *constant enough* I'm afraid. Use a macro instead.

Comment: what do you mean by constant enough? can you please explain

Comment: Old compiler? Need to upgrade?

Comment: I can use the macro, but wondering why the size marked const causes a compilation error.

Comment: There is your answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702629/c-error-expression-must-have-a-constant-value) (edited link)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In C language keyword `const` has nothing to do with *constants*. In C language, by definition the term "constant" refers to literal values and enum constants. This is what you have to use if you really need a *constant*: either use a literal value (define a macro to give your constant a name), or use a enum constant.

(Read here for more details: [Shall I prefer constants over defines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308194/shall-i-prefer-constants-over-defines/2308364#2308364))

Also, in C99 and later versions of the language it possible to use non-constant values as array sizes for local arrays. That means that your code should compile in modern C even though your `size` is not a constant. But you are apparently using an older compiler, so in your case

```
#define SIZE 10
```

is the right way to go.

Comment: Thanks thought it was the same as C++.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in another stackoverflow question, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702629/c-error-expression-must-have-a-constant-value)

> it's because In C objects declared with the const modifier aren't true
>   constants. A better name for const would probably be readonly - what
>   it really means is that the compiler won't let you change it. And you
>   need true constants to initialize objects with static storage (I
>   suspect regs_to_read is global).

Comment: Variable length arrays are supported in C11, so perhaps the OP's compiler is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on C99 your IDE compiler option may have a thing called variable-length array (VLA) enable it and you won't get compile error, efficiently without stressing your code though is with  MALLOC or CALLOC.

static const int size = 10;

```
void foo() {
    int* array;
    array = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
}
```