# Visual Studio Code tells me expression must have a constant value, even though the expression does

Tags: c

I have a snippet of C code that looks like this

```
const size_t scratch_size = 256;

char scratch[scratch_size];
```

It compiles without error or warning, but Visual Studio Code has underlined scratch_size  (see attached fig) and says "expression must have a constant value". Is scratch_size not considered constant by Visual Studio Code? Shouldn't my compiler (icx) complain?

[image]

Comment: The IntelliSense parser used by the editor is not the same as the compiler. It's known for making mistakes. The compiler itself is the final arbiter for what is valid or not (though with all the non-standard extensions added it can't always be trusted either, but at least more than the editor).

Comment: `char scratch[scratch_size];` is a VLA because `scratch_size` is not an integral constant expression. (Making the variable `const` does not make it one.) It depends on your compiler and chosen C language standard whether VLAs are supported.

Comment: MSVC compiler does not allow this: `scratch_size` is a constant variable, but it is not a "constant expression". You might use `#define SCRATCH_SIZE 256`

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the intel compiler icx is ok with this but VS is configured with the assumption that I am using MSVC compiler

Comment: So is the above snippet considered bad practice since it will break with some compilers?

Comment: @DJames Regardless, it is unlikely that you actually want a VLA here. With `#define SCRATCH_SIZE 256` instead it will be a normal fixed-size array.

Comment: @DJames There are many compilers, the VSCode IntelliSense can't keep track of all of them and their extensions and peculiarities. It uses its own parser with its own set of rules.

Comment: The VLA is best used when the size isn't known until run time. It's non-portable code too.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ok I will use your precompiler suggestion.

Comment: @WeatherVane VLAs are only non-portable to compilers that fail to support **last century's** C99.  And **this** century is well-nigh 1/4 over already...

Comment: @AndrewHenle VLAs are optional. Since C11 I think.

Comment: @DJames What scope does your `char scratch[scratch_size];` array have?  If it's at file scope, or if it's `static`, you can't use a VLA because `scratch_size` is not an [integer constant expression](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p6).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245173/array-definition-expression-must-have-a-constant-value

Comment: @AndrewHenle Both `scratch` and `scratch_size` have function scope. They are local variables discarded after a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantics of `const` is that it cannot change after declaration.  It is not however 'known' at compile time as required by an array dimension where VLA is not supported.

VLA in C99 was widely regarded as a *bad idea* and since C11 it was made *optional* for a compiler to support, which generally makes it's use ill-advised at best.  It is possible that your compiler supports it but that your code editor/static analysis is advising against it.

I would suggest either:

```c
#define SCRATCH_SIZE 256
char scratch[SCRATCH_SIZE] ;
```

or

```c
char scratch[256] ;
const size_t scratch_size = sizeof(scratch) / sizeof(*scratch) ;
```

Note that your original code would be valid C++ code, where the semantics of `const` differ.  Note however that C++ does not support VLAs so while it could be valid C, it would not be so for the same reason it is valid C++.

Comment: *VLA in C99 was widely regarded as a bad idea and since C11 it was made optional*  VLAs are necessary to dynamically allocate or pass to a function an actual multidimensional array without all but the outermost dimension fixed at compile time, and they're back to being mandatory in C23, albeit with a different name.

Comment: @AndrewHenle VLAs with automatic storage duration are still optional in C23. Support for pointers to VLAs is mandatory in C23. The interpretation of the conditionally defined `__STDC_NO_VLA__` macro has changed in C23 accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  Noted.  In my work a stable standard is more important than new features.  Most are of little interest to me in embedded systems.  In any event I long since switched to C++ and have largely ignored C development since C99 (or C++ since C++14 for that matter).  Code reusability and portability over a variety of platforms and compilers is often more important than playing with all the new toys.  It leads to a rather conservative approach with respect to language features.