# How can an array of structs be initialized using a const struct in global scope?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I want to use code similar to the following (but a lot more complex - this is a simplified example) to initialize an array of structures, but during compilation I get the error "expression must have a constant value".

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} windowStruct_t;

static const windowStruct_t windowStructInit =
{
    .x = 3,
    .y = 5,
};

// These get defined differently at times.  This is simplified for the example.
#define NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS (2)
#define REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES(x) (x),(x)

// The following line causes the error "expression must have a constant value" twice.
windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = 
    { REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES( windowStructInit ) };

void someFunction( void )
{
    volatile int x = windowStruct[0].x;
}

void anotherFunction( void )
{
    volatile int y = windowStruct[1].y;
}
```

Manually expanding the macro and replacing the line that causes the error with the following gives the same result:

```
windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = 
    { windowStructInit, windowStructInit };
```

But this compiles without error:

```
windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] =
    { { .x = 3, .y = 5 }, { .x = 3, .y = 5 } };
```

If I move the array declaration inside of function scope, it compiles without errors (I am ignoring the fact that someFunction() and anotherFunction() now access different arrays and that their lifetimes are different):

```
void someFunction( void )
{
    windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = 
        { REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES( windowStructInit ) };

    volatile int x = windowStruct[0].x;
}

void anotherFunction( void )
{
    windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = 
        { REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES( windowStructInit ) };

    volatile int y = windowStruct[1].y;
}
```

Leaving the array declarations inside of function scope, if they are declared to be "static", the error message comes back:

```
void someFunction( void )
{
    static windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = 
        { REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES( windowStructInit ) };

    volatile int x = windowStruct[0].x;
}
```

So it seems that when the arrays are declared as automatic variables (on the stack) that they can be initialized in a way that isn't allowed when the memory allocation is static (whether inside function scope or in global scope where the allocation is static even without the "static" keyword).  Is there a way to initialize the array in global scope using a const struct as in the original example?

I am using C, not C++.  I don't want to use dynamic memory allocation.  The compiler is TI's ARM compiler V16.6.0.STS as included in their Code Composer Studio environment.

Comment: Try to define `windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = ...` as `static const windowStruct_t windowStruct[ NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS ] = ...` and see what happens.

Comment: When it is in global scope, I get the same compilation error with "static", "const", "static const" or neither of them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist stop guessing, this is C, not some C++.

Comment: @SteveStrobel `const struct`s are not compile-time constants. And "even without the static keyword" is because you're confusing the `static` storage class with *static storage duration* :)

Comment: repeating the initializer is correct, now write an answer about it and self-accept it. The other cannot be done, ever, at all.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala. Fair enough. I simply had no clue :) Since you know the answer, why not post it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The root of my question is, "Why does using a const struct as an initializer work with arrays declared as automatic, but not if declared static?"  Not being compile-time constants might explain why they wouldn't work in either case, but I don't see how it explains the difference in the two cases.

Comment: It exactly explains it, the initializer need not be a constant for variables with automatic storage duration.

Comment: I'd rather close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11702629/918959) than write more answers :D

Comment: The reason is that all variables with static storage duration are initialized at some point before main() is called. Meaning they can't depend on any run-time values. Unfortunately, the C language don't regard `const` variables as compile-time constants. It is a known language flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `const` object is not a C *constant*.  Instead use *constants* which is required for  non-automatic storage objects.

Define an initializer `{ .x = 3, .y = 5 }`

```
typedef struct windowStruct_s {
  int x;
  int y;
} windowStruct_t;

#define windowStruct_t_default_initializer { .x = 3, .y = 5 }
#define NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS (2)
#define REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES(x) x, x /* no () */

windowStruct_t windowStruct[NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS] = {
    REPEAT_NUM_ARRAY_ELEMENTS_TIMES(windowStruct_t_default_initializer) };

int someFunction(void) {
  volatile int x = windowStruct[0].x;
  return x;
}

int anotherFunction(void) {
  volatile int y = windowStruct[1].y;
  return y;
}
```